# Can i make a filter for what files will be printed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to make a program that can call .bat files. I figured it out how to display all files in the folder, but i want to display just some files and with less informations.

I searched how to do this, but i didn't found something helpful for me. Maybe i didn't put the question right on google.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::string folder = "C:\\Windows\\Test";
std::string resfolder = "C:\\Windows\\Test\\Resources";

void ListFiles()
{
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(folder))
    std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ListFiles();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to show just the name of the file without the path and the extension and if is a file named "private" or "admin" to not be displayed.

Comment: Sure, the `directory_entry` has all the information you need in the `path` you already use (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) and you can write an `if` for the name however you want them to be shown or not

Comment: ***if is a file named "private" or "admin" to not be displayed*** If `std::filesystem` does not have this, wouldn't the code be like less than 4 lines of code in your for loop to add such a feature? I mean once you get the name if (( name == "admin" ) || (name == "private")) { // don't display } else { // display }

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i understand. But, how i make the condition? In batch is simple `if exist name.bat ( echo. )` or like this. In c++ is `if(entry.path!=Name)` ?

@drescherjm I can put just `if((name!="admin")||(name!="private"))` . It's not more simple? :)))

Comment: `if((name!="admin")||(name!="private"))` Would be wrong. Any value for name would make that true. You could do `if((name!="admin") && (name!="private")) {`

Comment: @drescherjm you're right. Have to be both true to pass that names . But, i didn't figured out so far how to remove extension ".bat". I check that link sent by @SamiKuhmonen and i found a modifier: `remove_filename - removes filename path component` . I don't know how to add that modifier to my code... :| Can you help me with that?

Comment: The first comment should have taken care of that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem